# How can I create a new instance of a subclass from a static method in its superclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract singleton class and I want it to have an `instance` field that represents the singleton's instance. I tried doing this:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    private static AbstractClass instance;

    public static AbstractClass getInstance() {
        return instance == null ? this.getClass().newInstance() : instance;
    }    
}
```

I want this to function so that when I call it from a subclass of `AbstractClass` it returns an instance of that subclass, not an instance of `AbstractClass`, which is why I tried using `this#getClass()` instead of just `AbstractClass`. This of course gives me an error stating "Cannot use this in a static context". Is there a way I can generate a new instance of a subclass in a static method in its superclass?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` can not be used inside a `static` method because there is no explicit object to resolve for the `this` reference.

In addition to this constraint, `Parent` class does not know about the possible subclasses(unless `sealed`) that can extend from it.

So, it can't create an explicit instance of a subclass.

Based on your problem, you may want to approach some form of `Factory` pattern to manage object creation. (or other creational pattern)